# MySQL SUBSTRING() with non-utf8 encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding

I've got a MySQL database with `latin1` encoding, and I'm struggling with function `SUBSTRING()` which is obviously counting bytes and not characters, as shown by the following scenario:

```
MySQL [hozana]> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [hozana]> SELECT SUBSTRING('ééééé', 1, 3);
+-------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('ééééé', 1, 3)      |
+-------------------------------+
| ééé                           |
+-------------------------------+
```

Everything normal up to now, let's switch the connection to `latin1` encoding.

```
MySQL [hozana]> set names latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [hozana]> SELECT SUBSTRING('ééééé', 1, 3);
+-------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('ééééé', 1, 3)      |
+-------------------------------+
| é�                             |
+-------------------------------+
```

The only way I found right now, is to convert string to utf-8 before function SUBSTRING() and convert it back to latin1 afterwards. Which is very ugly...

```
MySQL [hozana]> select convert(cast(convert(substring(convert(cast(convert('éééé' using  latin1) as binary) using utf8), 1, 3) using utf8) as binary) using latin1);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| convert(cast(convert(substring(convert(cast(convert('éééé' using  latin1) as binary) using utf8), 1, 3) using utf8) as binary) using latin1)     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ééé                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My question is, which is the right configuration to make in order to have `SUBSTRING()` working in `latin1`?

**Note**

Here is the configuration before and after `set names`:

```
MySQL [hozana]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.54    |
+-----------+

MySQL [hozana]> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [hozana]> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+

MySQL [hozana]> set names latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [hozana]> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | latin1 |
| character_set_connection | latin1 |
| character_set_database   | latin1 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | latin1 |
| character_set_server     | latin1 |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User error.

When you say `SET NAMES latin1`, you are announcing to MySQL that the bytes coming from the client (you) are encoded in latin1.  But they weren't.  They were still in utf8.

When you typed `ééééé`, the bytes generate were these *10* bytes `C3A9C3A9C3A9C3A9C3A9`  Those were sent to mysql as *10* latin1 characters, namely `Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã©`.  `SUBSTRING`, as requested, carved off the first 3 characters (but they were latin1 characters:  `Ã©Ã`, hex `C3A9C3` and delivered them back to your UTF-8 client, which proceeded to interpret `C3A9` as `é`, then gagged on the invalid UTF-8, hex C3, and puked on your terminal with its black diamond `�` (the "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER").

So, always be sure to establish the *encoding of the client*, either via something in the connection mechanism or with `SET NAMES`.  All sorts of nasties can occur if you specify it incorrectly.  Alas, [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) does not address your problem directly; but it addresses a lot of other things that can happen.

Oh, another thing.  You say you have "a MySQL database with latin1 encoding".  That is OK.  You must still specify the client to be encoded in (apparently) `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.  MySQL will convert to the encoding of the *column* when you do an `INSERT`, and convert back the other way when you do a `SELECT`.  Since `é` exists in `latin1` as well as `utf8`, (and ditto for all other Western European accented letters), all should be well.

Perhaps you crafted the Question with a literal.  Well, that does not necessarily reflect `SELECTing` from a table.  So, I crafted a table with both a latin1 column and a utf8 column, each containing `ééééé`, verified that the HEX and LENGTH were different.  Then testing `SELECT SUBSTRING(col, 1, 3)` correctly produced `ééé` in both cases.

Comment: Many many thanks for your accurate reply, nobody really explained me the encoding staff with mysql, and you did it very well! I know what's wrong with my code now. Cheers

Comment: @etiennecallies - Thanks.  If it is any consolation, it took me years to understand the _many_ things that can go wrong with MySQL charsets, and be able to explain it.  Furthermore, your case was something that I have never seen before. 
 I had to run some tests to figure out how to reproduce it, then adapt my understanding to explain it.